# is this the correct way to iterate through a pointer to pointer in a struct in c?

Tags: c, pointers

Is this even going in the right direction? I was getting a segfault before but now I can't tell if this is doing what I think it's doing. The structure Vertex has a pointer to pointer array to other Vertex structures that are neighbors to it. I need to iterate through these neighbors.

```
//v is pointer to a Vertex
for(int i = 0; i < v->numNeighbors; i++)
{
    //if(!(inCirDeque(c, v->neighbors[i])))
    if(!(inCirDeque(c, &(*((*v).neighbors)[i] )) ))
    {                       
        //addBackCirListDeque(c, v->neighbors[i]);
        addBackCirListDeque(c, &( *((*v).neighbors)[i]));
    }
}


/* Double Link Struture */
struct DLink {
  TYPE value;           /* value of the link */
  struct DLink * next;  /* pointer to the next link */
  struct DLink * prev;  /* pointer to the previous link */
};

/* Deque Structure based on Circularly-Doubly-Linked List */
struct cirListDeque {
  int size;             /* number of links in the deque */
  struct DLink *last;   /* pointer to the last link */
};
typedef struct cirListDeque cirListDeque;

struct Vertex {
    char label;
    int isVisited; /* Use this boolean to remember where you have been */

    int numNeighbors;
    struct Vertex** neighbors; /* array of pointers to Vertex which are adjacent to THIS */
};
typedef struct Vertex Vertex;
```

Comment: `&(*((*v).neighbors)[i] )` is the same as `((*v).neighbors)[i]` (or `(v->neighbors)[i]` or simply `v->neighbors[i]`), if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: if v is a pointer to a Vertex wouldn't v->neighbors dereference the v pointer to Vertex itself , needing one more * and then the [ ] ?

Comment: I'm getting confused what you're trying to ask. Could you rephrase it a bit?

Comment: since v is a struct Vertex *v doesn't the first  v->neighbors refer to a Vertex **neighbors? So then you would need one more * and a [ ] ?

Comment: "_doesn't the first v->neighbors refer to a Vertex **neighbors?_" -- Yes. "_So then you would need one more * and a [ ] ?_" -- Yes, but depends on what you want to do. In your code you use `&`. It cancels out the final `*` and thus, both can be removed. So `&(*((*v).neighbors)[i] )` can be simplified to `v->neighbors[i]`

Comment: I see. The thing is I need a pointer for the functions, that's why I put the &. Is there some way I could get an address without canceling what I did?

Comment: "_Is there some way I could get an address without canceling what I did?_" -- Uh. Didn't I tell you twice? `v->neighbors[i]`?